# Wrapping LLM deployed in azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, langchain, mlflow

I have deployed a LLM model on azure databricks. I can access it via the databricks API:

```
Https://adb-17272728282828282.1.azuredatabricks.net/serving-endpoints/my-code-llama/invocations
```

I am aware that langchain supports Databricks directly but is it possible to say wrap the databricks cluster in mlflow/openai wrapper or something so that I can use it in langchain like this:

```
Llm = ChatOpenAI(
   openai_api_base="http://my-url/API"
   openai_api_key="7282"
   model_name= "my-code-llama"
   max_tokens =1000,
   streaming=True,
   callbacks= [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
)
```

Trying to do so as there are alot of limitations if I just use the langchain Databricks wrapper directly. I am quite new so some support would be really great!

Comment: what are limitation you are facing in langchain Databricks wrapper. Add more details of your error and limitations.

Comment: You can use the databricks serving endpoint directly in `ChatOpenAI`. Did you tried that?

Comment: @JayashankarGS streaming for eg is not supported when I use the Databricks langchain wrapper. How do U use the Databricks endpoint with ChatOpenAI? It gave me errors saying endpoint not found. U have sample code?

Comment: I have provided the solution. kindly check it

Comment: You can use streaming in databricks langchain wrapper. Try this 

```chunks = []
llm = Databricks(endpoint_name="databricks-mpt-7b-instruct")
async for chunk in llm.astream("hello. tell me something about yourself"):
    chunks.append(chunk)
    print(chunk, end="|", flush=True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the requirements for [wrapping a model serving endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/en/large-language-models/langchain.html#wrap-a-model-serving-endpoint) in Databricks:

- A registered LLM deployed to a Databricks model serving endpoint.
- CAN QUERY permission to the endpoint.

Install the latest `langchain` on the cluster library and restart the cluster.

[image]

Use the code below.

```py
from langchain.llms import Databricks

llm = Databricks(endpoint_name="databricks-mpt-7b-instruct")
llm("How are you?")
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to use this endpoint directly in `langchain`, try the code below.

Install `langchain-openai` as shown in the above steps.

**Note**: Make sure to use a model of the correct task type. Below, I used the model (`databricks-llama-2-70b-chat`) for the task `chat`.

```py
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAI
from langchain.callbacks import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

chat_llm = ChatOpenAI(
   openai_api_base="https://<xxxxxx>.azuredatabricks.net/serving-endpoints",
   openai_api_key="dapi-xxxxx",
   model_name= "databricks-llama-2-70b-chat",
   max_tokens =1000,
   streaming=True,
   callbacks= [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
)

chat_llm.invoke("What is mlflow?")
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to serve this in a custom endpoint, you need to use `langserve` with deploying it in the cloud.

Refer to this [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/langserve#server) for more information.

Comment: I have the the foundation model running in the "serving" tab and have the URL. You mentioned to download langchain in "Compute" tab. How is this linked to the model? I did not need to touch the compute tab when I served the foundation model

Comment: I asked to install  `langchain` in libraries tab under compute configuration, which is required for the code.

Comment: Default packages in databricks runtime may not be the latest version so i asked to install.

Comment: You can also use this code in local with latest langchain packages but need to configure env vars endpoint and key.